# SonarQube: query to export all issues of a specific project

Tags: sonarqube

in SonarQube 4.5 I usually export all violations of a specific project by doing this query:

```
SELECT
    issues.id, 
    severity as criticality,
    IFNULL(rules.name, plugin_rule_key) as name,
    message,
    projects.name,
    projects.kee,
    projects.long_name,
    line,
    rules.plugin_rule_key,
    rules.plugin_name
    FROM issues
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projects ON projects.id = issues.component_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rules ON rules.id = issues.rule_id
WHERE
    issues.status = 'OPEN'
    AND projects.enabled = 1
    AND issues.root_component_id = XXXXXX
```

where XXXXXX is the numerical id of the interested project I want to export.
Now we moved to SonarQube 5.6 and the above query no more work.
The database is a bit different from previous version and I tried to modify the query in this way:

```
SELECT
   issues.id,
   severity as criticality,
   IFNULL(rules.name, plugin_rule_key) as name,
   message,
   projects.name,
   projects.kee,
   projects.long_name,
   line,
   rules.plugin_rule_key,
   rules.plugin_name
FROM issues
   INNER JOIN projects ON projects.project_uuid = issues.project_uuid
   INNER JOIN rules ON rules.id = issues.rule_id
WHERE
   issues.status = 'OPEN'
   AND projects.enabled = 1
   AND projects.root_id = XXXXXX
   --AND issues.project_uuid = 'XyzWXyzWXyzWXyzWXyzW'
```

The query not work and the sql client run out of memory... tried also filtering by issues.project_uuid with the same rusults.
I need this kind of export because I then create an excel sheet with some pivot table and calculation.
What is the correct query for version 5.6?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is only one reason you should treat the database as a black box, and use web services instead.

Comment: In an ideal world I agree with you, but to do the same things I have to call the API search multiple times (500 object limits and pagination required) and the data returned non contains all info like the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the correct way to join the issues table with the relative project.
This is now the correct query that works perfectly with SonarQube 5.6 mySql database:

```
SELECT issues.id, 
      severity as criticality, 
      IFNULL(rules.name, plugin_rule_key) as name, 
      message, 
      projects.name, 
      projects.kee, 
      projects.long_name, 
      line, 
      rules.plugin_rule_key, 
      rules.plugin_name 
 FROM issues 
      INNER JOIN projects ON projects.uuid = issues.component_uuid 
      INNER JOIN rules ON rules.id = issues.rule_id 
 WHERE issues.status = 'OPEN' AND projects.enabled = 1  AND projects.root_id = XXXXXX;
```